# Replacing OS X with Linux or Unix, and making the switch to Tiling Window Managers

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, efi, grub

I have a Macbook Pro 8,2 and really want to make the switch to something a little less stubborn and a little more flexible than the proprietary Mac OS X. I am a bit frustrated with MacPorts lately and Homebrew. I also would like to make the transition to a tiling window manager such as Awesome, RatPoison, or Xmonad. In the past I have had problems getting the Mac's wireless card working as well as setting up the EFI installer to boot to GRUB or LILO. So, I am curious if anyone here has had any experiences with running a Linux Distro like Slackware, Archlinux, Debian or a Unix OS such as FreeBSD on their MacBook Pro.

Comment: In order to avoid answers of the form "Yes, I *have* run Linux on my MacBook!", would you provide a little more detail about what specific aspects you're interested in?

Comment: You'll probably get a better response over at the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @AndrewYoung I've successfuly installed Ubuntu on Macbook don't remember the kind back in 2010, just for testing and trying. As I recall everything worked outofthebox.